# Data binding failure, as the variable does not update its value

Tags: angular, typescript, global

I have this 'errors' message component. It uses data-binding to get its text, so i just created a function that gets as parameter the message that should show. This is the idea:

```
<div id="success"> {{message}} </div>
```

The component:

```
  message: string = "Something went wrong";

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  callMessage(msg: string) {
    this.message= msg;
    $("#success").animate({
      'top': '10px'
    });
  }
```

You see, `message` gets its value from whoever is calling it. The problem is that inside the callMessage() function, the value does get updated, but the global varible is not changing. I looked this up in the web, and tried things like `window.message` and `window[message]`, tho none of it seems to work. I have also tried removing that fixed message 'Something went wrong', but the variable just remains null. I have also tried calling the function from the ngOnInit, but without success, i can't delete the callMessage() and just paste it inside ngOnInit, because it does not accepts parameters.

That causes the message component to always show the fixed message (or nothing, without it). Funny thing is that this should work. Inside this very same project i did many other functions that work by changing global values, and the passing it t the DOM. But for some reason, this example seems to fail.

What could be causing this?

note: If you need any other piece of code, please feel free to say it, and just for clarification, the callMessage() is called in the main ngOnInit of the web-app

Edit: Someone asked for the decorator, so here's a better look:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messages',
  templateUrl: './messages.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messages.component.css'],
  providers: [MessagesComponent]
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {
```

And this is how i'm calling it:

```
ngOnInit() {

  this.toggleSuccess('Test');

}

toggleSuccess(msg: string) {

  this.messagesComponent.callMessage(msg);

}
```

and of course, i have a `<app-messages></app-messages>` in the main.html

obs: those are separated methods because i'm usually calling the toggleSuccess from main, instead of extending the message to the full project (as the mainComponent is already provided)

Comment: Can you show the @Component decorator of this class and how do you call this callMessage method in your main ngOnInit?

Comment: Does the component have the OnPush strategy?

Comment: Try calling this method in `ngAfterViewInit` (https://angular.io/api/forms/NgForm#ngAfterViewInit) of the `web-app`.

Comment: @Arif there it is :)

Comment: @Bardr it does not work either :/

Comment: It would be great if you could provide StackBlitz demo.

Comment: Why are you not using inputs?

Comment: @ConnorsFan the `toggleSuccess()` is caled onInit. as the page loads, the message should load. The coponent is working, but the message does not change. There is another function calling it tho, it calls `toggleSuccess()`after recieving a 'true' return from my api, but the same error happens

Comment: @ritaj how could i achieve this with inputs?

Comment: How are you getting the `messagesComponent` at your main component? You are calling him in `ngOnInit` so I suppose you are not using `@ViewChild`.

Comment: `<app-messages [message]="message"></app-messages>`  
...  
`_message: string;
@Input('message')
set message(message: string): void{
    this._message = message;
    $("#success").animate({
      'top': '10px'
    });
}
`

Comment: @Bardr yeah, not using `@ViewChild`. The message is a parameter, and it does reach `callMessage()` correctly

Comment: @CH4B, Can you show the definition of messagesComponent? How do you access that without @ViewChild/ViewChildren?

Comment: @Arif The first thing i do is set the messagesComponent as a provider, like `providers: [MessagesComponent]`, and then i import it in the mainComponent's constructor like `protected messagesComponent: MessagesComponent`. From that, i can just call messagesComponent using the main

Comment: Interesting, I reproduced your issue and it just don't work for `providers`. With `@ViewChild` everything's fine.

Comment: @CH4B, And do you have <app-messages></app-messages> in your HTML? If yes - There are two separate instances. What is displayed has nothing to do with what is being provided

Comment: @Arif I tried removing it, but the messageComponent is not showing up anymore. How should i approach it then?

Comment: I am going to write an answer with different approach. Because what you are doing is not correct

Comment: @Arif all right, waiting for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Arif stated in comments your approach is wrong.

> There are two separate instances. What is displayed has nothing to do with what is being provided.

Among the other options you can use singleton service approach: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xe52wh) demo (which is the best solution imho).

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is not correct. You shouldn't inject components.

What you should do is:

Either - use @ViewChild and call it only in or after ngAfterViewInit

Or - Create a service, and use ComponentFactoryResolver to dynamically insert view.

Or - Create a singleton service (provide in root), create a Behaviour, listen to that subject from your error component.

```
@Injectable({
    provideIn: 'root'
})
export class ErrorService {
    public error = new BehaviourSubject(null);
}
```

Inject it to your app.component and send message

```
constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) {

}

ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.errorService.error.next('Your message');
}
```

And in your app-error component do this

```
  message: string = "Something went wrong";

  constructor(private errorService: ErrorService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.errorService.error.subscribe(error => {
      if (error !== null) {
        this.callMessage(error);
      }
    })
  }

  callMessage(msg: string) {
    this.message= msg;
    $("#success").animate({
      'top': '10px'
    });
  }
```

Note: Please recheck my code for typos as I'm writing this using mobile phone.

Comment: Imho, option with singleton is the best. Changing message in `ngAfterViewInit` using `@ViewChild` probably would raise `Expression has changed after it was checked` error.

Comment: Not working. The message is showing empty. Could you explain your logic?

Comment: Also, i used a console.log for (error), and got 799 messages in my console stating ("your message")